# is there a way to check if a function is defined?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

i'm new in wolfram-mathematica and I wanna know if is there a way to know if a function is already defined. I mean. Is there something like`SomeFunction[f[i,j+1]]` that returns `True` or `False`?

I've been trying with `ValueQ` function but, it apparently doesn't work for that kind of arguments, `j+1`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can evaluate `?f`

Comment: seek [checking-if-a-symbol-is-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599241/checking-if-a-symbol-is-defined)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a symbol is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599241/checking-if-a-symbol-is-defined)

Comment: Hi, many thanks by reply. Well, i was expecting that `ValueQ` would help me, but when i use `ValueQ[f[j,k+1]]` it returns `True` even when `f[j,k]` is not defined. So, it did not work as i wanted.