# How to check if a symbol is already defined

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This question has been asked before in 2011 ([Checking if a symbol is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599241/checking-if-a-symbol-is-defined)), however, since then Mathematica has had several major versions.

As such I am wondering if there is a simpler solution to the problem of checking if a certain symbol has already been defined (to avoid overwriting it)? `ValueQ` apparently has some flaws and the other answers provide rather complicated solutions to such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

In what situations are you concerned about 'overwriting it'. If it is a symbol that you have defined you can `Protect` it.

```
Remove[x];
x = 1;
Protect[x];

x = 2
(* Set::wrsym: Symbol x is Protected. *)
```

If you are concerned about shadowing, use [Contexts](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html).

**Update**

```
symbols = Names["Global`*"];
NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test.nb"}], InsertResults -> False];
Complement[Names["Global`*"], symbols]
(* {"xyzzy"} *)
```

Comment: Assume I know nothing about the notebook and what symbols it has defined (I also can't assume any symbols are protected as I do not know the contents of the notebook). I now wish to define some number of symbols myself, but do not want to overwrite ones that have already been defined. I agree that one possible solution would be the use of a context. This however does not answer the original question.

Comment: @Qubit Added example to address your use case.